# Is better/faster/lighter to inject with metatag or with getters? actionscript 3 / flex

Tags: actionscript-3, robotlegs, swiftsuspenders

I would like to know which one is better/faster/lighter?

```
[Inject]
public var myInjection:MyInjection;
```

OR

```
[Inject]
public var injector:IInjector;

protected var _myInjection:MyInjection;

public function get myInjection():MyInjection{
    if(!_myInjection) _myInjection = injector.getInstance(MyInjection);
    return _myInjection;
}
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the first one is appropriate. The second is weird.

You've injected the IInjector in a couple of questions. In all of the robotlegs apps I've built I have *never* needed to inject the injector. The only time I've needed to do that is when I was writing framework extensions/utils.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that the first is faster. SwiftSuspenders keeps a cache of injection points for each injectee - the second method would probably not take advantage of that caching.